# What does "Ihr gesellschaftspolitisches Interesse und Engagement" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase

Do they want me to write something political? What kind of things does this sentence include?

EDIT: It was an application for regarding to scholarship. I assume they are trying to search for a person who is socially active.

Comment: please add some more context... also you should include some assumptions on your side, else this might get closed as a translation request, which is OT as of http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/343/when-is-a-translation-request-to-german-off-topic

Comment: Please also note that this question may not be allowed to be asked in a job interview in Germany (unless you had applied for a job with a political party, newspaper, or similar, where your political attitude matters). Links: http://www.dgb.de/themen/++co++07483a76-fee8-11df-463e-00188b4dc422 http://www.zeit.de/karriere/bewerbung/2013-03/arbeitsrecht-fragen-bewerbungsgespraech http://www.faz.net/aktuell/wirtschaft/karrieresprung-verbotene-fragen-im-vorstellungsgespraech-1726720.html (but IANAL)

Comment: For example: http://www.boell.de/de/navigation/bewerbung-1080.html it seems to me, however, that this is not a question about the German language.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about German culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're asking about your **sociopolitical interests** and if you're **politically active**.

So there's no need to go far afield. Answering those shouldn't be that complicated if you're interested in politics, if not it should be even easier.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on who the sponsor is, they might not be asking about party politics. You could list work for charitable causes, protection of the environment, work in a sports club, etc. They ask if you have a well-rounded personality with interests beyond pure academia.

It would be a different case if the scholarship is from an overtly political organization.